# "Feature '94c94ca6-b32f-4da9-a9e3-1f3d343d7ecb' is Web-scoped, and cannot be added to the Site."

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell

I am trying to activate Sharepoint Server publishing feature in a sharepoint online Subsite but getting error :

> Feature `94c94ca6-b32f-4da9-a9e3-1f3d343d7ecb` is Web-scoped, and
>   cannot be  added to the Site.

I tried :

```
$site =$context.Site
$site.Features.Add($feature,$isActivate,[Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FeatureDefinitionScope]::None)
```

What property I should use instead of `$site` ?

Comment: replace `$site.Features.Add` with `$context.Web.Features.Add` and check

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$context.Site` gives you the site collection context.

Feature with GUID `94c94ca6-b32f-4da9-a9e3-1f3d343d7ecb` is `SharePoint Server publishing feature` which as your error mentions is a web-scoped feature and not site collection scoped feature. So, you need to activate it in the SP Web context and not SP Site context.

So, modify it as in below snippet to activate it in your subsite:

```
$context.Web.Features.Add($feature,$isActivate,
[Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FeatureDefinitionScope]::None)
```